# How to split the string value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2008

I want split the string by semicolon. string value come with semicolon sometimes without semicolon.

Example #1:

```
String = abceder-ere1212;eferere2121212 (with Semicolon)
```

Output

```
string1 = abceder-ere1212
string2 = eferere2121212
```

Example #2:

```
String: abcederdfdfd (without Semicolon)
```

Output

```
string1 = abcederdfdfd
string2 = ''
```

The below code is working, **but I want to use in multiple places in the query**, need a function instead of below code.

```
DECLARE
    @remarks varchar(max),
    @vc_pen varchar(max), 
    @vc_adjust varchar(max)

Select @remarks  = remarks    
from table1

SELECT   
   @vc_pen = SUBSTRING(S, 1, P - 1),
   @vc_adjust = SUBSTRING(S, P + 1, L - P)
FROM 
   (SELECT
        S = @remarks,
        P = CHARINDEX(';', @remarks),
        L = LEN(@remarks)) s;
```

How to write a query or function to split the string? Kindly assist

Comment: If it's always just 0 or 1 semicolon, just write a function that checks it with charindex, and in case it's -1 returns the whole thing in first part and if not, return the 2 parts using left / right or substring.

Answer (score 0):

Try something generic like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION split
( 
    @string VARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
)  RETURNS @output TABLE(index INT, splitteddata VARCHAR(MAX)) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT, @index INT
    SELECT  @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string), @index = 1
    WHILE   @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF  @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitteddata)  
        VALUES(@index, SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @index = @index + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)
    END 
   RETURN 
END

Query:
SELECT *
FROM split('abceder-ere1212;eferere2121212',';')
Output:
1 abceder-ere1212
2 eferere2121212
```

Comment: thanks. But I need to get a output 1 and output2, if i want output 1 then i need to get first string before semicolon, if output 2 then i need to get second string after semicolon. How to acheive

Comment: If i get you right then you will need to call the function twice by adding additional parameter which string index you need..

Comment: I need to get one output at a time either before semicolon or after semicolon. How to get it. Please assist.

Comment: Does that makes sense now? When you split now, you get index as well with it.

Comment: Query is not executing, showing error. Can you please check ur posted query

Comment: Was missing end statement!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this....

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID INT, Value VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES 
 (1 , 'abceder-ere1212;eferere2121212')
,(2 , 'abceder-ere1234')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT ID
       ,REPLACE(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'), '000000', '') Value
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) Output_Value
FROM   (SELECT ID
               ,Cast ('<M>' + Replace(CASE WHEN Value NOT LIKE '%;%' THEN  Value + ';000000'
                                     ELSE Value END
                      , ';', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data
        FROM   @Table) AS A
       CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

**Result**

```
╔════╦═════════════════╦══════════════╗
║ ID ║      Value      ║ Output_Value ║
╠════╬═════════════════╬══════════════╣
║  1 ║ abceder-ere1212 ║            1 ║
║  1 ║ eferere2121212  ║            2 ║
║  2 ║ abceder-ere1234 ║            1 ║
║  2 ║                 ║            2 ║
╚════╩═════════════════╩══════════════╝
```

**If there are only Two possible values**

you can do the following

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID INT, Value VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES 
 (1 , 'abceder-ere1212;eferere2121212')
,(2 , 'abceder-ere1234')
```

**Query**

```
;WITH CTE AS 
( SELECT  ID 
         ,REPLACE(CASE WHEN Value NOT LIKE '%;%' 
               THEN  Value + '|000000'
               ELSE Value END, ';', '|') AS Value
  FROM @Table
)
SELECT ID
      ,LEFT(Value , CHARINDEX('|', Value) -1) FirstValue
      ,REPLACE(RIGHT(Value,  LEN(Value) - CHARINDEX('|', Value)), '000000', '') SecondValue
FROM CTE
```

**Result Set**

```
╔════╦═════════════════╦════════════════╗
║ ID ║   FirstValue    ║  SecondValue   ║
╠════╬═════════════════╬════════════════╣
║  1 ║ abceder-ere1212 ║ eferere2121212 ║
║  2 ║ abceder-ere1234 ║                ║
╚════╩═════════════════╩════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `PARSENAME` function like this:

```
SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(@remarks, ';', '.'), 2) AS string1,  
       PARSENAME(REPLACE(@remarks, ';', '.'), 1) AS string2
```

---

Here is a code that will give your parts in separated fields:

```
DECLARE @text VARCHAR(1000);
SET @text = 'SELECT ''' + REPLACE(@remarks, ';', ''',''') + ''''
EXEC(@text)
```

In another way this is better (with sending result to a table):

```
DECLARE @text VARCHAR(1000)
SET @text = 'SELECT ''' + REPLACE(@remarks, ';', ''' As part union all SELECT ''') + ''' As part'
EXEC(@text)
```

And changing above to below for having a resultTable:

```
SET @text = 'SELECT part INTO resultTable FROM (select ''' + REPLACE(@remarks, ';', ''' As part UniON ALL SELECT ''') + ''' As part) dt '
```

I think this answer is useful when you set the results to a `datatable` or as result of a `stored procedure`.

Comment: If you want you can send fields to a temp-table and use them ;). I know this is not a direct answer, but I hope it will help.